# Installing Keras/Tensor Flow on R

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to install tensorflow on R. As far as I understand I have already installed successlly many times but it won't load

Everytime I run a function from Tensorflow and Keras it does not work.

```
> testlabels=to_categorical(trainy)
Error: Python module tensorflow.python.keras was not found.

Detected Python configuration:

python:         C:\Users\AUSTER~1\ANACON~1\python.exe
libpython:      C:/Users/AUSTER~1/ANACON~1/python37.dll
pythonhome:     C:\Users\AUSTER~1\ANACON~1
version:        3.7.3 (default, Apr 24 2019, 15:29:51) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Architecture:   64bit
numpy:          C:\Users\AUSTER~1\ANACON~1\lib\site-packages\numpy
numpy_version:  1.16.4
tensorflow:     [NOT FOUND]
```

When I load the libraries I have no issues. They all load up sucessfully.

```
library(EBImage)
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)


I have ran all these following commands.
install.packages("keras")
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("EBImage")

install.packages("reticulate")
install.packages("remotes")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")

reticulate::py_discover_config("keras")
reticulate::py_discover_config("tensorflow")

install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
tensorflow::install_tensorflow()
devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")
```

What could be causing the issue. After I installed tensforflow it said "`Installation Complete`" and then restarted R. Is R simply unable to find the installation?

I have also ran the following commands still with no luck.

```
library(tensorflow)
Sys.setenv(TENSORFLOW_PYTHON="/usr/local/bin/python")
```

**Update**

I was able to get Tensorflow/Keras to work by opening an Anaconda command prompt and running the following commands. Then my R code using Keras/Tensorflow started to work.

```
conda install -c conda-forge keras
```

Comment: Did you install keras for python.  keras for R depends on the availability of keras for python. For windows,  this needs to be done through anaconda.

Comment: I installed keras using the following command : `devtools::install_github("rstudio/keras")`. Do I need to install manually through anaconda navigator?

Comment: I believe that what you did installed the R package. But that depends on the python package which you must install separately.

Comment: I see. So I would have to install Keras through python like all python users. Ok I will figure that out. I am not an expert in python.

Comment: Many thanks G5W it worked. :-) If you would like please make an official response and I will give you upvote your answer/find it complete. Many thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keras package makes use of keras through python. When you install the package, it installs the R interface, but *not* the python package. You must separately install the python package. There is a nice guide for doing that on [RBloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/a-newbies-install-of-keras-tensorflow-on-windows-10-with-r/)

Answer (score 0):

I checked all of the suggestions. None of them worked.
This worked for me on Windows 10

1- Open rstudio and uninstall these package if you already installed using:

```
uninstall.packages(c("keras", "tensorflow","tfruns"))
```

2- uninstall rtools from your computer if exists

3- Install Anaconda from https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual

4- Install the last version of rtools from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/

5- Close rstudio if it is opened

6- open new session and write this:

```
install.packages("reticulate")
install.packages("remotes")
library("reticulate")
remotes::install_github("rstudio/tensorflow")
library(tensorflow)
install_tensorflow(version = "2.0.0b1", method = "conda", envname = "r-reticulate")

remotes::install_github("rstudio/keras", dependencies = TRUE)
library(keras)
```

7- check if they work:

#if tensorflow works

```
tf$abs(-1)
```

#if keras works

```
mnist <- dataset_mnist()
```

Answer (score 0):

my suggestion is to install anaconda and create an environment called "r-reticulate".

you can do it using anaconda navigator or

```
reticulate::conda_create(envname = "r-reticulate")
```

then to check that env detected by reticulate, use `reticulate::conda_python()`.it must return directory of python.exe for your env.
after that you can install tensorflow by `install_tensorflow()`. [not working in my case]

so I install the tesnorflow from CMD.
follow these steps:

1. open the cmd :]
2. activate the `r-reticulate` env using `conda activate r-reticulate` (you may need your directory to conda directory if you did not add conda to your PATH)
3. use : `conda install -c anaconda tensorflow`

now in R, you can use TensorFlow.
for installing Keras, you can use `pip install Keras`. [I tried install_keras() function after the installation of tensorflow, but it n